# Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am running into a protractor issue i.e. `Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL`

From my protractor.conf.js:

```
onPrepare: function () {
    //Mail config
    require('./test/e2e/config/mailin.js');
}
```

Here is the mailin.js config:

```
var mailin = require('mailin');

    mailin.start({
    port: 2525,
    disableDNSValidation: true,
    disableWebhook: true // Disable the webhook posting.
});

mailin.on('startMessage', function (connection) {
    console.log(connection);
});

/* Event emitted after a message was received and parsed. */
mailin.on('message', function (connection, data, content) {
    console.log(data);
    /* Do something useful with the parsed message here.
     * Use parsed message `data` directly or use raw message `content`. */
});


var getLastEmail = function () {
    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    console.log("Waiting for an email...");

    mailin.on('message', function (connection, data, content) {
        deferred.fulfill(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};

var extractToken = function (email) {

    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

    var pattern = /\/#\/useraccount\/activate\/(\S+)">/g;
    var result = pattern.exec(email.html);
    var token = result[1];

    deferred.fulfill(token);
    return deferred.promise;
};

global.getLastEmail = getLastEmail;
global.extractToken = extractToken;
```

And finally my test case:

```
describe('Signup page', function () {
    var signupPage = new SignupPage();

    beforeEach(function () {
        signupPage.get();
    });

    it('should allow user to signup', function () {
        signupPage.chooseParentsType();
        signupPage.typeFirstName('Julien');
        signupPage.typeEmail('me@bignibou.localhost');
        signupPage.typePassword('------');
        signupPage.typeAddress('5 rue Sainte Anast');
        signupPage.scroll();
        signupPage.firstAddress();
        signupPage.signup();

        browser.controlFlow().execute(getLastEmail).then(extractToken).then(showToken);
    });

    function showToken(token){
        console.log('And the token is... ', token);
    };
});
```

I get the following error from protractor:

```
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
warn: Either spamassassin or spamc are not available. Spam score computation is disabled.
Started
info: Mailin Smtp server listening on port 2525
.         Waiting for an email...
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the WebDriver Control Flow.
F

Failures:
1) Signup page should allow user to signup
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at [object Object]._onTimeout (/Users/julien/Documents/projects/bignibou/bignibou-site/node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js:1812:23)

2 specs, 1 failure
```

Can someone please help?

**edit**: Here are the versions used by my app:

```
package.json

{
  "name": "bignibou-client",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.12.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "assemble-less": "~0.7.0",
    "bower": "1.6.2",
    "flow": "~0.2.3",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "~2.1.2",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.12.1",
    "grunt-mkdir": "~0.1.2",
    "grunt-usemin": "~2.6.2",
    "karma": "~0.13.15",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.5.3",
    "karma-htmlfile-reporter": "~0.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~0.3.7",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
    "mailin": "^3.0.1",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "protractor": "2.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node_modules/.bin/bower install"
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that `getLastEmail` never completes?

Comment: Hi. You're right. I am realizing that the trouble is that no email is delivered to  the mail server and therefore getLastEmail never completes. Thanks a lot!!!